# Fetch generated values from php file and display it in android

Tags: java, php, android, session-variables

Here i am using php file to store data from android to the remote Database.
Now in my android project i am having register page.When i press register it will call php file and store data to databse. Here in my php file i am getting two values from database, i.e:

```
  $_SESSION['fullname'] = $row['fullname'];
  $_SESSION['vault_no'] = $row['vault_no'];
```

Now i have to display these values (fullname and vault_no) in a seperate activity when a register button is pressed. what extra code i have to add to achieve this one..please help me.. i am new to android.Thanks in advance..

**Register.php**

```
<?php

    session_start();
    define('HOST','localhost');
    define('USER','username');
    define('PASS','password');
    define('DB','dbname');

    $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');

    $salutation = ($_POST['salutation']);
    $fname = trim($_POST['fname']);
    $lname = trim($_POST['lname']);
    $dob = trim($_POST['dob']);
    $mobile = trim($_POST['mobile']);
    $country = trim($_POST['country']);
    $state = trim($_POST['state']);
    $city = trim($_POST['city']);
    $pin = trim($_POST['pin']);

    $sql = "SELECT mobile FROM users WHERE mobile = '$mobile' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    if(mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["error_msg"] = "user already existed with" . $mobile;
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else
    {
        $characters = '0123456789';
        $uuid = '';
        $random_string_length = 5;

        for ($i = 0; $i < $random_string_length; $i++)
        {
            $uuid .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
        }

        $fullname = $fname . " " . $lname;
        $vault_no = $salutation . "" . $country . "" . $pin . "" . $uuid;

        $sql = "insert into users (salutation,fname,lname,fullname,"
        ."dob,mobile,country,state,city,pin,unique_id,vault_no,created_at) "
        ."values ('$salutation','$fname','$lname','$fullname',"
        ."'$city','$pin','$uuid','$vault_no',now())";

        if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
        {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE mobile = '$mobile' LIMIT 1";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $response["error"] = false;
                $_SESSION['fullname'] = $row['fullname'];
                $_SESSION['vault_no'] = $row['vault_no'];
                $response['fullname'] = $row['fullname'];
                $response['vault_no'] = $row['vault_no'];
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in registration!";

            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }

    mysqli_close($con);

?>

<script>
    alert("your message");
    document.location = "formprofile.php"
</script>
```

**MainActivity.java** (register page)

```
package com.example.server;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

---

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation", "unused" })
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    // array to save Salutation code
    private static final int[] SalutationCode
        = new int[]{0,1,2};

    // array to show Salutation
    private static final String[] Salutation
        = new String[]{"Salutation","Mr","Ms"};

    // array to save Country code
    private static final int[] CountryCode
        = new int[]{0,91};

    // array to show Country name.
    private static final String[] Country
        = new String[]{"Country","India"};

    // array to save City code
    private static final int[] CityCode
        = new int[]{0,1};

    // array to show City list
    private static final String[] City
        = new String[]{"City","Bangalore"};

    // array to save State code
    private static final int[] StateCode
        = new int[]{0,1};

    // array to show State list
    private static final String[] State
        = new String[]{"State","Karnataka"};

    int selectedAreaCode;
    private Spinner spin;
    private Spinner spin1;
    private Spinner spin2;
    private Spinner spin3;
    private EditText editTextFname;
    private EditText editTextLname;
    private EditText editTextDob;
    private EditText editTextMobile;
    private EditText editTextPin;
    private Button register;
    //private Button login;
```

---

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        spin=(Spinner)
            findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spin1=(Spinner)
            findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        spin2=(Spinner)
            findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        spin3=(Spinner)
            findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
        editTextFname=(EditText)
            findViewById(R.id.editTextFname);
        editTextLname=(EditText)
            findViewById(R.id.editTextLname);
        editTextDob=(EditText)
            findViewById(R.id.editTextDob);
        editTextMobile=(EditText)
            findViewById(R.id.editTextMobile);
        editTextPin=(EditText)
            findViewById(R.id.editTextPin);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adpt_area
            = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                Salutation);

        adpt_area.setDropDownViewResource(
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spin.setAdapter(adpt_area);

       /* ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinner1
                = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.country_arrays,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
          spinner1.setDropDownViewResource(
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
          spin1.setAdapter(spinner1);
      */

        ArrayAdapter<String> adpt_country
            = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Country);
        adpt_country.setDropDownViewResource(
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spin1.setAdapter(adpt_country);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adpt_city
            = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, City);
        adpt_city.setDropDownViewResource(
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spin2.setAdapter(adpt_city);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adpt_state
            = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, State);
        adpt_state.setDropDownViewResource(
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spin3.setAdapter(adpt_state);

    }
```

---

```
    public void Register(View view)
    {
        String fname =
            editTextFname.getText().toString();
        String lname =
            editTextLname.getText().toString();
        String dob =
            editTextDob.getText().toString();
        String mobile =
            editTextMobile.getText().toString();
        String pin =
            editTextPin.getText().toString();

        int selectedPosition =
            spin.getSelectedItemPosition();
        // get area code based on value selected in spinner
        String salutation =
            String.valueOf(SalutationCode[selectedPosition]);

        int selectedPosition1 =
            spin1.getSelectedItemPosition();
        // get area code based on value selected in spinner
        String country =
            String.valueOf(CountryCode[selectedPosition1]);

        int selectedPosition2 =
            spin2.getSelectedItemPosition();
        // get area code based on value selected in spinner
        String state =
            String.valueOf(StateCode[selectedPosition2]);

        int selectedPosition3 =
            spin3.getSelectedItemPosition();
        // get area code based on value selected in spinner
        String city =
            String.valueOf(CityCode[selectedPosition3]);

        insertToDatabase(salutation,fname,lname,
                dob,mobile,country,state,city,pin);
    }
```

---

```
    private void insertToDatabase(String salutation,
        String fname, String lname,String dob, String mobile,
        String country, String state, String city, String pin)
    {
        class SendPostReqAsyncTask
            extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
        {
            @SuppressWarnings({"unused","deprecation"}) @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params)
            {
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                String paramSalutation = params[0];
                String paramFname = params[1];
                String paramLname = params[2];
                String paramDob = params[3];
                String paramMobile = params[4];
                String paramCountry = params[5];
                String paramState = params[6];
                String paramCity = params[7];
                String paramPin = params[8];
                //InputStream is = null;
                String fname =
                    editTextFname.getText().toString();
                String lname =
                    editTextLname.getText().toString();
                String dob =
                    editTextDob.getText().toString();
                String mobile =
                    editTextMobile.getText().toString();
                String pin =
                    editTextPin.getText().toString();

                 int selectedPosition
                     = spin.getSelectedItemPosition();
                 // get area code based on value selected in spinner
                 String salutation
                     = String.valueOf(
                     SalutationCode[selectedPosition]);

                 int selectedPosition1
                     = spin1.getSelectedItemPosition();
                 // get area code based on value selected in spinner
                 String country
                     = String.valueOf(
                     CountryCode[selectedPosition1]);

                 int selectedPosition2
                     = spin2.getSelectedItemPosition();
                 // get area code based on value selected in spinner
                 String state
                     = String.valueOf(
                     StateCode[selectedPosition2]);

                 int selectedPosition3
                     = spin3.getSelectedItemPosition();
                 // get area code based on value selected in spinner
                 String city
                     = String.valueOf(
                     CityCode[selectedPosition3]);

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs
                    = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new
                    BasicNameValuePair("salutation", salutation));
                nameValuePairs.add(new
                    BasicNameValuePair("fname", fname));
                nameValuePairs.add(new
                    BasicNameValuePair("lname", lname));
                nameValuePairs.add(new
                    BasicNameValuePair("dob", dob));
                nameValuePairs.add(new
                    BasicNameValuePair("mobile", mobile));
                nameValuePairs.add(new
                    BasicNameValuePair("country", country));
                nameValuePairs.add(new
                    BasicNameValuePair("state", state));
                nameValuePairs.add(new
                    BasicNameValuePair("city", city));
                nameValuePairs.add(new
                    BasicNameValuePair("pin", pin));

                try
                {
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost
                        = new HttpPost("http://oursite/regsiter.php");
                    httpPost.setEntity(new
                        UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response
                        = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    //is = entity.getContent();
                }
                catch (ClientProtocolException e)
                { }
                catch (IOException e)
                { }

                return "success";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result)
            {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                          result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //TextView textViewResult = (TextView)
                //        findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);
                //textViewResult.setText("Inserted");
                editTextFname.setText("");
                editTextLname.setText("");
                editTextDob.setText("");
                editTextMobile.setText("");
                editTextPin.setText("");
            }
        }

        SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask
            = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();

        sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(salutation,fname,
            lname,dob,mobile,country,state,city,pin);

    }
```

---

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

---

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: send the required parameters as a response from your php file and then in android parse that response and store that data locally and pass it other activity

Comment: i am sending the response from php file..but i dont know how to parse and store it.can u please ellaborate..?

Comment: post your response then I can tell accordingly

Comment: here i am using this snippet to send response from php file..$_SESSION['fullname'] = $row['fullname'];
        $_SESSION['vault_no'] = $row['vault_no'];
        $response['fullname'] = $row['fullname'];
        $response['vault_no'] = $row['vault_no'];
        echo json_encode($response);

Comment: response you get in java is what I meant not php code

Comment: i dont  know how to get the responsee in java..can u please guide me how to get that one..

Comment: you are getting it in onPostExecute method. result variable that you are passing in Toast is your response . You can either print it or Log it to see it

Comment: here i am getting success as a toast message.how can i print those fullname and vault_no values..

Comment: why only success where are other values??

Comment: if i press register button..i am getting only success as toast message sir.

Comment: then send those parameter in response from your php file

Comment: sir look at the php code  i have posted..i am sending those parameters..

Comment: sir if you are having any idea about this..please post the code as a answer.so that it would be helpfull to me..

Comment: Let me clear my self with your requirement,  You actually want that when a person get register, it will move to next activity in android and after that he will get the value (fullname and vault_no)from server to display in that activity??? Is it your requirement???

Comment: yes sir..that is my requirement.

Comment: ok, please tell me, when a user fills the registration form and hit the register button. does he hits the server to get register??? and how you will get to know that he is registered now??? are you giving any response back from server?

Comment: yes the data is saving in the database..i mean the entered values are storing in the database..

Comment: no sir..i am not giving any response back from server..we manually check whether the registration is done by looking at the database.

Comment: ok, what if he is not filling any required field or wrong entry, how you will inform him that he is doing something wrong???

Comment: if(TextUtils.isEmpty(fname)) {
                 editTextFname.setError("please enter first name");
                    return fname ;
                 } like this i am checking for every field..if the field is empty it will show error message.

Comment: haha, Brother, generate some response from server for registration confirmation. Create a Json response at the time of registration. success 1 or 0, if success is 1 then move to next activity else something went wrong. additional, you can add these two required fields in that json too. So when the person will hit the server, he will get 3 elements in json, 1) success 2) fullname 3) vault_no. and save these value in preferences and print them in next activity

Comment: sir as i am new to this both android and php..can u please suggest me any link for the tutorial..or else can u please modify the code..